# how do you pull data from json using jsonpath syntax

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a json file like this and I need to pick:
timestamp, values and group it by dimensions.

the json file looks like this:

```
{
"totalCount": 10,
"nextPageKey": null,
"result": [
{
"metricId": "builtin:host.cpu.usage,
"data": [
{
"dimensions": [
"HOST-1234"
],
"dimensionMap": {
"dt.entity.host": "HOST-1234"
},
"timestamps": [
1642606200000,
1642606800000,
1642607400000,
1642608000000,
1642608600000,
1642609200000,
1642609800000
],
"values": [
40.86490249633789,
38.45122528076172,
38.24514389038086,
52.10111999511719,
51.01322937011719,
40.43871307373047,
40.392024993896484
]
},
```

I need to be able to extract timestamp and values group by dimensions from this json using json path.

I have tried this:

```
$.data['timestamps']
$.data['values']
```

not returning any data, any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update (original answer below)

First, let's correct your data so that it's actually valid JSON

```json
{
  "totalCount": 10,
  "nextPageKey": null,
  "result": [
    {
      "metricId": "builtin:host.cpu.usage",
      "data": [
        {
          "dimensions": [
            "HOST-1234"
          ],
          "dimensionMap": {
            "dt.entity.host": "HOST-1234"
          },
          "timestamps": [
            1642606200000,
            1642606800000,
            1642607400000,
            1642608000000,
            1642608600000,
            1642609200000,
            1642609800000
          ],
          "values": [
            40.86490249633789,
            38.45122528076172,
            38.24514389038086,
            52.10111999511719,
            51.01322937011719,
            40.43871307373047,
            40.392024993896484
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now that I can properly see the structure, my suggestion would be

```
$.result[*].data[*]['timestamps','values'][*]
```

Breaking this down:

```
$.result                                         get `result` property
        [*]                                      get all array elements
           .data                                 get `data` property
                [*]                              get all array elements
                   ['timestamps','values']       get `timestamps` and `values`
                                          [*]    get all array elements
```

This will give the result set:

```json
[
  1642606200000,
  1642606800000,
  1642607400000,
  1642608000000,
  1642608600000,
  1642609200000,
  1642609800000,
  40.86490249633789,
  38.45122528076172,
  38.24514389038086,
  52.10111999511719,
  51.01322937011719,
  40.43871307373047,
  40.392024993896484
]
```

The `[*]` at the end is what returns all of the values themselves.

Since you want them grouped, you *could* remove the `[*]` and get this

```json
[
  [
    1642606200000,
    1642606800000,
    1642607400000,
    1642608000000,
    1642608600000,
    1642609200000,
    1642609800000
  ],
  [
    40.86490249633789,
    38.45122528076172,
    38.24514389038086,
    52.10111999511719,
    51.01322937011719,
    40.43871307373047,
    40.392024993896484
  ]
]
```

Where each sub-array is the value at `timestamps` and `values` respectively.

However, that only works when you have a single array element at `result` and `data`.  If you add more elements, you'll get separate sub-arrays for their contents.

You can try all of this out at my playground, https://json-everything.net/json-path.

---

(original response, retained for posterity)

`$.data['timestamps']` or simply `$.data.timestamps` is just going to return the array under `timestamps`.  To get the values in the array you need to add `[*]` to the end.

```
$.data.timestamps[*]
```

Many implementations also support multiple keys in the `[ ]` selector, so you could get both `timestamps` and `values` values at the same time with

```
$.data['timestamps','values'][*]
```

but be aware that you'll get a single list with all of the values, possibly without any context as to where those values originated.  To resolve this, your implementation *may* support returning the path to each value as well.

Comment: Why * at the end?? data is itself an array so the query should be something like $.data[ *]['timestamps'] or $.data[ *]['values'] or $.data[ *]['timestamps','values']

Comment: The `[*]` returns the values inside the arrays.  Basically it deconstructs them.  What you posted would give the arrays themselves.  JSON Path doesn't do grouping. It just gives values.  Getting them as arrays could be used as that grouping, but it may have undesired impacts as well depending on the data, like getting multiple `timestamps` arrays.

Comment: To be clear, the result in JSON would be nested arrays without the `[*]`: `[[ <timestamp strings> ], [ <value strings> ]]`

Comment: OP has clearly  stated that $.data['timestamps']
$.data['values'] is not returning any data. So I doubt appending * at the end will make any difference. I tested your query and it did not work. If there is any online tester which gives results for your query do share

Comment: Edited answer.  The original JSON data was faulty, and OP neglected to add the path up to the data they were searching for.
I'm an implementor of JSON Path, and I'm a member of the group working to standardize the syntax.

Comment: @gregsdennis I need to group this data by "dimensions" field to have multiple series. Any ideas?

Comment: I saw you other question about grafana.  I'm not familiar with that application.  I don't know what it supports.  Json path isn't going to group results for you.  I think you need something else or something custom.

Comment: @gregsdennis how can I disppay this data "dimensions","timestamps","values" format using jsonpath?

Comment: It sounds like you want data transformation.  JSON Path isn't going to do that for you.  You need another tool.